# How do I read text from non visible elements with Watir (Ruby)?

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

There is a div on a page that is not visible but has some value I want to capture. Calling text on it returns me an empty string.

How do I get the value displayed without having to deal with the raw html? Can I force .text to return me the actual value regardless of the visiblity of the text in the browser?

```
irb(main):1341:0> d.first.visible?
=> false

irb(main):1344:0> d.first.html
=> "<div class=\"day\">7</div>"

irb(main):1345:0> d.first.text
=> ""
```

PS: There are many many divs (the page is caching response and display them accordingly). I considered changing all the display:none in the page or clicking to make them visible but I'd prefer to avoid this if possible.
If not possible a solution with changing all the display none would be the preferred work around.

PPS: Damned, I tried to overload the visible? method in the Watir::Element class to always return true, but that didn't do the trick.

```
irb(main):1502:0> d.first.visible?
=> true

irb(main):1504:0> d.first.text
=> ""
```

Comment: Are you using watir-classic, watir-webdriver or both? While the behaviour is the same in both gems, I think the workaround would be different.

Comment: gem 'watir-webdriver' using firefox

Comment: What about parsing that HTML?

Comment: That's what I do but that's not correct to spread HTML syntax knowledge to the user of this gem. Not to mention maintenance efforts with regex. The lib should really have something like innerHtml that should not care about visible or not, since I can query that myself. The text/value function has some *extra* built-in intelligence that should not be there.

Comment: @Jeremy I agree, maybe @ŽeljkoFilipin will know more..
Regex? http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/1136008
Use f.e. Nokogiri: `value = Nokogiri::HTML("<div class=\"day\">7</div>").text # => "7"`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Everytime I use regex, I end up with 2 problems :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the newer versions of Watir, there is now an `Element#text_content` method that does the below JavaScript work for you.

```
e = d.first
e.text_content
#=> "7"
```

**For Old Versions of Watir (Original Answer):**

You can use JavaScript to get this.

```
e = d.first
browser.execute_script('return arguments[0].textContent', e)
#=> "7"
```

Note that this would only work for Mozilla-like browsers. For IE-like browsers, you would need to use `innerText`. Though if you are using watir-classic it would simply be `d.first.innerText` (ie no `execute_script` required).

***Using attribute_value:***

Turns out you can make it simpler by using the `attribute_value` method. Seems it can get the same attribute values as javascript.

```
d.first.attribute_value('textContent')
#=> "7"
```

***Using inner_html***

If the element only includes text nodes (ie no elements), you can also use `inner_html`:

```
d.first.inner_html
#=> "7"
```

Comment: Clever work around! Thanks Justin. That did the trick indeed. It's quite verbose but works. Thanks. I'll accept the answer if no one come up with a more clever answer, but you got my +1 for sure! Many thanks.

Comment: If you need to do this often, you could always add it as a method to the Element class.

Comment: This is is awesome. I like it.

Comment: @davidXYZ, FYI, the current version of Watir now has an `Element#text_content` method for doing this (see updated answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `execute_script` method do change the value of "visible" to visible. Something like `document.getElementById('id').style.visibility = 'visible'` assuming it has an ID. If it does not you can always ask the devs to put a test-id on the element (or just do it yourself).