# ruby Webdriver: how to access invisible div's text?

Tags: ruby, selenium, watir-webdriver

Developer exposes few internal values I need for testing as a display:none div:

```
<div class="veryuniqueclass" style="display:none;">&amp;QSC=11221.00&amp;QSN=11194.00&amp;CPCWC=0.02&amp;CPCN=790</div>
```

I need for futher calculations to capture text in that div (i.e. *"&QSC=11221.00&QSN=11194.00&CPCWC=0.02&CPCN=790"*).

I have a webdriver elements for those divs. Browser element is variable b:

```
infoElements = b.divs(:class => "veryuniqueclass")
i1 = infoElements[0]
```

*i1.text* returns an empty string instead of a string with parameters I'm expecting. How to access what's between div and /div?

Answer (score 0):

Found [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14748645/how-do-i-read-text-from-non-visible-elements-with-watir-ruby):

```
b.execute_script('return arguments[0].textContent', i1)
```

^ that returns: &QSC=11307.20&QSN=11250.50&CPCWC=0.02&bid=155"

Answer (score 0):

If that is the only div with class `veryuniqueclass`, this should work:

```
browser.div(:class => "veryuniqueclass").text
```